# Stored procedure not finding when calling concurrent web api requests

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures

Hi i have a get api which is requesting data from 3 stored procedures , its working fine when it calls only single time but it fails when this api calls multiple times simoltaneousely , like when it calls 10 times , 2-3 time it fails and send exception that it not find the stored procedure
this is my function

```
 public  POSCustomerDetailResponse POSCustomerDetail(string BranchID, string CustomerCode, string AllBranches, string CurrentDate)
        {
            POSCustomerDetailResponse objDetails = new POSCustomerDetailResponse();
            int GramentDue = 0, UnderProcess = 0;
            double AmountDue = 0.0;
            int PendingOrder = 0;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_CustomerAllStoreData";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flag", 3);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchId", BranchID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustCode", CustomerCode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedBranch", AllBranches);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilterFlag", 3);
            ds = Appclass.GetData(cmd);
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                dt = ds.Tables[0];
                foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    GramentDue = GramentDue + Convert.ToInt32(dtrow["ReadyClothes"].ToString());
                    AmountDue = AmountDue + Convert.ToDouble(dtrow["Balance"].ToString());
                    UnderProcess = UnderProcess + Convert.ToInt32(dtrow["BalQty"].ToString());
                }
                PendingOrder = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            }
            objDetails.PendingOrders = PendingOrder;
            objDetails.DueAmt = Math.Round(AmountDue, 2);
            objDetails.ReadyPcs = GramentDue;
            objDetails.UnderProcessPcs = UnderProcess;

            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            ds1 = GetCustRatings(CurrentDate, BranchID, CustomerCode);
            if (ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                objDetails.AllRating = Convert.ToInt32(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AllRating"]);
                objDetails.CurrentRating = Convert.ToInt32(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CurrentRating"]);
                objDetails.IsActive = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IsActiveCust"].ToString();
                objDetails.IsNewCustomer = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["NewCustomer"].ToString();
                objDetails.CustomerAtRisk = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerOverDue"].ToString();
            }

            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
            ds2 = GetPackageDetails(CustomerCode, CurrentDate, BranchID);
            if (ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                objDetails.PackageName = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PackageName"].ToString();
                objDetails.PackageStartDate = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["StartDate"].ToString();
                objDetails.PackageExpiryDate = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EndDate"].ToString();
            }
            var dsCust = GetCustomerDetails(BranchID, CustomerCode);
            if (dsCust.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                objDetails.MemberShipId = dsCust.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MemberShipId"].ToString();
                objDetails.CurrencyType = dsCust.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CurrencyType"].ToString();                
            }

            return objDetails;

        }
```

and this is my function to set connection and fill data

```
  public static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        sqlConStr = strSqlConn();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlConStr);
        SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter();
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        adap.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adap.Fill(ds, "table");
        con.Close();
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact exception message and detail?

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure 'sp_CustomerAllStoreData'. @Crowcoder

Comment: Shot in the dark, but you should never name procedures beginning with "sp". The master database will be searched first. I'm no dba but maybe possibly that has something to do with it.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the stored procedure?

Comment: What does the `strSqlConn()` method look like?